# Split single column data into multiple columns based on leap year in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

I have about 100 files of MS Excel which consist of weather data.

I need the data on yearly basis but the file has a single column with data of about 140 years and manually copy-paste is very time consuming. So, is there any way to split the data by using simple commands which can be dragged so that data of 1 years(365 cells) is copied in continuous rows.

Also, there is the leap year problem that data after every 3 years should be 366 cells instead of the rest 365 cells.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need a little more information from you. Please [edit] your question to include how the data is laid out and what you've tried so far. Please keep in mind this site isn't a service, rather a place to ask questions when you have attempted something and get stuck.

Comment: What is the actual date of the first data point? Are you looking to **transpose** the data? Or move it to another column? Or highlight different years different colors? Or are you looking to get an average? What is your goal?

Comment: The data in the excel file of about 140 years has been put into the column A with no break between months or years
Now i want to extract data of each year separately from column A into multiple columns such that column B has data of ist year, column C has data of secont year and so o.
The probllem now arises for the fourth year as the fourt year happens to be a leap year and data has to be of 366 cells and the fifth year should begin after that.
Please check the file also here[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZEv9Z5hX9ThEc38iXwRshiO7u0aWYGPaPihl1QdlNeQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Basically i have an excel [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZEv9Z5hX9ThEc38iXwRshiO7u0aWYGPaPihl1QdlNeQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0)
The data is all kept in column A with No break in between1
I want to split the data in multiple columns such that
Column B=1st 365 enteries of column A
Column C=2nd 365 enteries of column A
Column D=3rd 365 enteries of colum A
But, Column D=4th 366 enteries of column A
Column E=5th365 enteries of column A
Column F=6th 365 enteries of column A
Column G=7th 365 entries of colum A
But, Column H=8th 366 enteries of column A
and so on.

Comment: What year does it start with? Is the value in A1 the 1st of January Year 20XX?

Comment: it starts with 1961 & ends at 2099
.
the value in A1 is for ist jan 1961

Comment: And how is this to be laid out. For example, if you wanted to copy row A366 into B. Would that appear in B366 or in B1

Comment: >>B1
.
basically its a weather data file for daily temp from 1961 to 2099 but in a single column. i just want the data for each year separately. manual job is very tedios as i have to proceess aleast 50 files.

Answer (score 2):

As you can't seem to get the other macro working per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/753450/macro-fails-to-run-through-whole-of-the-sheet-excel), I figured I'd work with the hard facts you've presented here and make it easy for you.

For your specific date range, this macro will work -

```
Sub test()
'fill dates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim NumCells As Integer
NumCells = [counta(A:A)]
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Cells(1, 1) = "1/1/61"
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NumCells, 1)).DataSeries

'move data
Dim c As Range
Dim cCol As Integer
cCol = 4
label:
For Each c In Range("A:A")
If c.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To 366
        If Not Right(c, 4) = Right(c.Offset(i), 4) Then
         GoTo label2
        End If
    Next
label2:
        Range(c, c.Offset(i - 1, 1)).Copy
        Cells(1, cCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Range(c, c.Offset(i - 1, 1)).Delete xlShiftUp
        Range(Cells(1, cCol), Cells(366, cCol)).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        cCol = cCol + 3
        GoTo label

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is a much better answer than mine... Less code too...

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim otherRow As Integer
otherRow = 1

Dim year As Integer
year = 1

Dim column As Integer
column = 66 ' start on B

Dim preColumn As Integer
preColumn = 64

Do While (True)

If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
    Exit Do
End If

If (column > 90) Then
    preColumn = preColumn + 1
    column = 65
End If


If (preColumn = 64) Then

Range(Chr(column) & otherRow).Value = Range("A" & row).Value

Else

Range(Chr(preColumn) & Chr(column) & otherRow).Value = Range("A" & row).Value

End If


Dim addition As Integer
addition = 0

If (year = 4) Then
    addition = 1
End If

If (otherRow = 365 + addition) Then
column = column + 1
otherRow = 0

year = year + 1

End If


If (year > 4) Then
 year = 1
End If

row = row + 1
otherRow = otherRow + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Fairly useless screen shot of it working:

[image]

[image]

Please try it on a copy of your data... I'm not responsible for breaking everything. You will also need to test it properly and ensure all data is present, but I think it's fine.